# Does the decay of Fourier transform depend only on "geometry of singularities"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ and suppose that $\{ x \mid f(x) \leq 1 \}$ is diffeomorphic to a closed disk and $\nabla f(x)$ is not tangent to the circle $\{ x \mid f(x) = 1\}$. Put
$$
 g(x) = \max\{1-f(x),0\}.
$$Is it true that $\widehat g(\xi) = O(|\xi|^{-5/2})$, $|\xi|\to+\infty$, where $\widehat g$ stands for the Fourier transform? If I replace $g$ by
$$
  \widetilde g(x) = \max\{1-|x|,0\} \quad \text{near $|x|=1$}, \quad \text{some $C^\infty$ function for $|x|<1$},
$$
it looks like the singularities are essentially the same and I would expect the same upper bound on the rate (exponent) of decay, but is it a feasible approach?

Comment: "embedded disk" is unclear. $g$ is continuous, $C^\infty$ on $|x| < 1$ and zero on $|x| > 1$ ? In that case $g(x) = u(x) \varphi(x)$ where $u \in C^\infty_c$  and $\varphi(x) = \max(0,1-|x|^2)$ so $\hat{g}(\xi) = \hat{\varphi} \ast \hat{u} (\xi)$ and the decay of $\hat{g}$ is similar to the decay of $\hat{\varphi}$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes. I think it's more useful to use $\max(0,1-|x|)$ near $|x|=1$ since then it's radial derivative will have the same singularities as the indicator function of the unit disk for which the Fourier transform decays as $O(|\xi|^{-3/2})$. So it implies the decay $O(|\xi|^{-5/2})$ for the Fourier transform of the initial function?